# Escaping number in a regex replace

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to insert a numeral using a regex replace, but it confuses the interpreter.

Let's say I want to output "firstgroup-secondgroup":

```
Regex.Replace(mystring, pattern, "$1-$2")
```

But if I want to output "firstgroup0secondgroup":

```
Regex.Replace(mystring, pattern, "$10$2")
```

Is there any way to escape the 0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to enclose the `1` with curly braces:

```
"${1}0$2"
```

This works for named captures, too.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using named groups in the pattern (?<name>blah) and then ${name} but couldn't seem to get it to work. This works perfectly though.